# When does a power series in $O_K[[x]]$ have only finitely many zeros in $m_K$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

When does a power series in $O_K[[x]]$ have only finitely many zeros in $m_K$ ?

Here $O_K$ is the ring of integers of the field $K$ and $m_K$ is the unique maximal ideal. we can assume both $O_K$ and $m_K$ to be integral closure of corresponding things.

For example, if we consider $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$, $O_K=\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $m_K=p \mathbb{Z}_p$, then can we say that a power series in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ has only finitely many zeros in $m_K=p \mathbb{Z}_p$ ?

Comment: In $\mathbb Q_p$ case yes, since the zeros are isolated and $m_K$ is compact. The same works for any locally compact $K$.

Comment: @Wojowu, nice answer